# DNS using gethostbyname

Tags: c, dns, gethostbyname

I'm doing the following in C to get the ip address from a hostname. It prints IP is ? *?, so it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
 char * targetHostName = server_proxy_hostname;
 char * targetPort = server_proxy_port;
 struct hostent *info;
 info = gethostbyname(targetHostName);
 char ** ipAddresslist;
 ipAddresslist =info -> h_addr_list;
 char * ipAddress = ipAddresslist[0];

 printf("IP is %s\n", ipAddress);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that it returns a string (which is **not** the case).

[gethostbyname()](http://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/gethostbynameman.html)

> char **h_addr_list
>
> A list of IP addresses for this host. Although this is a char**, it's
>   really an array of struct in_addr*s in disguise. The last array
>   element is NULL.

You need to use [inet_ntoa(), inet_aton(), inet_addr](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/inet_ntoaman.html) in order to convert the value to the proper output format.